# Pandas DataFrame: Duplicate rows and multiply against array

Tags: python, pandas

I am have a dataframe 'df' with a value column. I also have an array with a list of percentages. How can I multiply the percentages against the df, whilst duplicating each row depending on how many are in the array?

I have found a way to do it using the repeat method, but this static and clunky. Is there a better way to this?

Below is an example

```
array = [0.2, 0.5, 0.7]
```

**df**

```
name value
name1 20
name2 10
```

Expected Output

```
name value
name1 4
name1 10
name1 14
name2 2
name2 5
name2 7
```

Comment: Can you provide your exact code? `repeat` is likely an efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to repeat the rows as many times as you have values is array, then [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to repeat the array as many times as you have rows and multiply:

```
out = (df
 .loc[df.index.repeat(len(array))]
 .assign(value=lambda d: d['value'].mul(np.tile(array, len(df))))
 #.reset_index(drop=True) # uncomment if a normal index is needed
)
```

Or using numpy:

```
out = (df
 .loc[df.index.repeat(len(array))]
 .assign(value=(df['value'].to_numpy()[:,None]*array).ravel())
)
```

output:

```
    name  value
0  name1    4.0
0  name1   10.0
0  name1   14.0
1  name2    2.0
1  name2    5.0
1  name2    7.0
```

##### alternative using `merge`

This is less elegant in my opinion as you create an intermediate column

```
out = (df
 .merge(pd.Series(array, name='factor'), how='cross')
 .eval('value = value*factor')
 .drop(columns='factor')
)
```